How to Optimize Monte Carlo Simulations with Parallel Processing in MATLAB?
I am trying to optimize a Monte Carlo simulation of an economic model involving three MATLAB files: StartMonCarFinal.m, SDsysFinal.m, and SDMasterFinal.m. Here's a brief overview of what each file does:

StartMonCarFinal.m: This is the main script that runs multiple Monte Carlo simulations. It repeatedly calls SDMasterFinal.m through a loop, with each iteration representing one simulation.
SDsysFinal.m: A function called by SDMasterFinal.m that handles updates of some internal system variables.
SDMasterFinal.m: The core script that performs the simulation, calling SDsysFinal.m and handling extensive data and computations.

To improve the simulation's running speed, I tried replacing the regular for loop in StartMonCarFinal.m with parfor to implement parallel processing. However, I encountered several issues during this attempt:

MATLAB indicates that the save command cannot be used within a parfor loop. I'm not sure how to overcome this limitation.
I am also concerned about the extensive use of global variables in SDMasterFinal.m, which might conflict with the parallelism of parfor.

I would appreciate any advice on how to effectively parallel process this type of Monte Carlo simulation, especially on how to handle the save issue in parfor loops and the problem with global variables. Any suggestions on how to enhance the parallel efficiency of such scripts would be very helpful.
Thank you for your time and assistance!

StartMonCarFinal.m

niter = 100; %number of random realizations for montecarlo

for mcar = 1:niter
    
    save mcar mcar niter
    mcar
    SDMasterFinal
    
    load mcar
    
    if mcar > 1
        load OutputFinal
    end
    
    
    wMC(mcar,:,:) = w;
    Z_MMC(mcar,:,:) = Z_M;
    Z_SMC(mcar,:,:) = Z_S;
    Z_M_MorMC(mcar,:,:) = Z_M_Mor;
    Z_S_MorMC(mcar,:,:) = Z_S_Mor;
    c_MMC(mcar,:,:) = c_M;
    c_SMC(mcar,:,:) = c_S;
    p_MMC(mcar,:,:) = p_M;
    p_SMC(mcar,:,:) = p_S;
    MMC(mcar,:,:) = M;
    SMC(mcar,:,:) = S;
    L_MMC(mcar,:,:) = L_M;
    L_SMC(mcar,:,:) = L_S;
    L_MNANMC(mcar,:,:) = L_MNAN;
    L_SNANMC(mcar,:,:) = L_SNAN;
    LMC(mcar,:,:) = L;
    R_MMC(mcar,:,:) = R_M;
    R_SMC(mcar,:,:) = R_S;
    phi_MMC(mcar,:,:) = phi_M;
    phi_SMC(mcar,:,:) = phi_S;
    thetaMC(mcar,:,:) = theta;
    Po_MMC(mcar,:,:) = Po_M;
    Po_SMC(mcar,:,:) = Po_S;
    taoMC(mcar,:,:) = tao;
    tao_SMC(mcar,:,:) = tao_S;
    tao_MMC(mcar,:,:) = tao_M;
    ES_MMC(mcar,:,:) = ES_M;
    UbarMC(mcar,:,:) = Ubar;
    RIMC(mcar,:,:) = RI;
    Z_MvecMC(mcar,:,:) = Z_Mvec;
    Z_SvecMC(mcar,:,:) = Z_Svec;
    
    save OutputFinal *MC niter
    
end

save OutputFinal





SDMasterFinal.m


clear all 

global t h_M h_S alfa gamma mu sigma l a ksi1 ksi2 Lbar kappa
global w Z_M Z_S Z_M_Mor Z_S_Mor c_M c_S p_M p_S M S L_M L_S L R_M R_S phi_M phi_S theta Po_M Po_S tao ES_M Ubar RI

%Parameter Values
beta = .9747;
h_M = 0.9;
h_S = 1.4;
alfa = -1.5;
mu = .6;
gamma = 1-mu; %(needs to be 1-mu);
sigma =.6;
l = 1:500;
a = 45; %Pareto coefficient
ksi1 = 1.142793;
ksi2 = 0.0082433;
delta = 7.5;
Lbar = 100;
kappa = 0.08;
T = 240;

%Allocate variables
w = zeros(length(l),T);
Z_M = zeros(length(l),T);
Z_S = zeros(length(l),T);
Z_M_Mor = zeros(length(l),T);
Z_S_Mor = zeros(length(l),T);
c_M = zeros(length(l),T);
c_S = zeros(length(l),T);
p_M = zeros(length(l),T);
p_S = zeros(length(l),T);
M = zeros(length(l),T);
S = zeros(length(l),T);
L_M = zeros(length(l),T);
L_S = zeros(length(l),T);
L_MNAN = zeros(length(l),T);
L_SNAN = zeros(length(l),T);
L = zeros(length(l),T);
R_M = zeros(length(l),T);
R_S = zeros(length(l),T);
phi_M = zeros(length(l),T);
phi_S = zeros(length(l),T);
theta = zeros(length(l),T);
Po_M = zeros(length(l),T);
Po_S = zeros(length(l),T);
tao = zeros(length(l),T);
tao_S = zeros(length(l),T);
tao_M = zeros(length(l),T);
ES_M = zeros(length(l),T);
Ubar = zeros(1,T);
RI = zeros(1,T);
Z_Mvec = zeros(length(l),length(l));
Z_Svec = zeros(length(l),length(l));

 


X0(1) = 0.0492; %Ubar(1) initial value for solver
X0(2) = 1.035; %p_M(1,1) initial value for solver
X0(3) = 0.054; %RI(1) initial value for solver

for t = 1:T
    
    %t
    
    %Initial Productivity
    if t == 1
        Z_M_Mor(:,1) = .8 + .4*l/length(l);
        Z_S_Mor(:,1) = 1*ones(length(l),1);
    end
        
    F=@(R)SDsysFinal(R);
    options=optimset('MaxFunEvals',10000000000,'TolFun',0.0001,'MaxIter',1000000,'Display','off');
    [X,Eval] = fsolve(F,X0,options);
    
    X0(1) = Ubar(t);
    X0(2) = p_M(1,t);
    X0(3) = RI(t);
    
    %Eval

    %Diffusion 
    for i = 1:length(l)
        for j = 1:length(l)
            Z_Mvec(i,j) = exp(-delta*abs(i-j)/length(l))*Z_M(j,t);
            Z_Svec(i,j) = exp(-delta*abs(i-j)/length(l))*Z_S(j,t);
        end
        Z_M(i,t+1) = max(Z_Mvec(i,:));
        Z_S(i,t+1) = max(Z_Svec(i,:));
        
        %Save Morning Productivity
        Z_M_Mor(:,t+1) = Z_M(:,t+1);
        Z_S_Mor(:,t+1) = Z_S(:,t+1);
    end
    
end




SDsysFinal.m

function D = SDsysFinal(X)

global t h_M h_S alfa gamma mu sigma l a ksi1 ksi2 Lbar kappa 
global w Z_M Z_S Z_M_Mor Z_S_Mor c_M c_S p_M p_S M S L_M L_S L R_M R_S phi_M phi_S theta Po_M Po_S ES_M Ubar RI

p_S(:,t) = ones(length(l),1);

Ubar(t) = X(1);
p_M(1,t) = X(2);
RI(t) = X(3);

Z_M(:,t) = Z_M_Mor(:,t);
Z_S(:,t) = Z_S_Mor(:,t);

for i = 1:length(l)

    %Wages and consumption
    
    w(i,t) = Ubar(t)*((((p_M(i,t)./h_M)/(p_S(i,t)./h_S))^(1/(alfa-1)))*p_M(i,t) + p_S(i,t))...
        ./(h_M*(((p_M(i,t)./h_M)/(p_S(i,t)./h_S))^(alfa/(alfa-1))) + h_S).^(1/alfa) - RI(t);
        
    c_S(i,t) = (w(i,t) + RI(t))./(p_M(i,t).*(((p_M(i,t)./h_M)/(p_S(i,t)./h_S))^(1/(alfa-1)))+p_S(i,t));
    c_M(i,t) = c_S(i,t).*(((p_M(i,t)./h_M)/(p_S(i,t)./h_S))^(1/(alfa-1)));
    
    %Choose phi
    phi_M(i,t) = 1-((Z_M(i,t)*p_M(i,t)*gamma)/(ksi2*(a-1)*((w(i,t)/(mu*p_M(i,t)))^((1-gamma)/gamma))))^(-1/2);
    phi_S(i,t) = 1-((Z_S(i,t)*p_S(i,t)*gamma)/(ksi2*(a-1)*((w(i,t)/(sigma*p_S(i,t)))^((1-gamma)/gamma))))^(-1/2);
    
    if phi_M(i,t) < 0
        phi_M(i,t) = 0;
    end
    if phi_M(i,t) > 1;
        phi_M(i,t) = 1;
    end
    if phi_S(i,t) < 0
        phi_S(i,t) = 0;
    end
    if phi_S(i,t) > 1;
        phi_S(i,t) = 1;
    end

    %Production and labor choices
    L_M(i,t) = (w(i,t)./(mu*p_M(i,t).*((Z_M(i,t)*(phi_M(i,t)/(a-1)+1)).^gamma))).^(1/(mu-1));
    L_S(i,t) = (w(i,t)./(sigma*p_S(i,t).*((Z_S(i,t)*(phi_S(i,t)/(a-1)+1)).^gamma))).^(1/(sigma-1));
    
    if (ksi1 + ksi2*(1/(1-phi_M(i,t))))*w(i,t) > (((Z_M(i,t)).^gamma)*p_M(i,t).*(L_M(i,t).^mu)/((a-1)^gamma))...
            *(((phi_M(i,t)+a-1)^gamma - (a-1)^gamma));
        phi_M(i,t) = 0;
        L_M(i,t) = (w(i,t)./(mu*p_M(i,t).*(Z_M(i,t).^gamma))).^(1/(mu-1));
    end
    if (ksi1 + ksi2*(1/(1-phi_S(i,t))))*w(i,t) > (((Z_S(i,t)).^gamma)*p_S(i,t).*(L_S(i,t).^sigma)/((a-1)^gamma))...
            *(((phi_S(i,t)+a-1)^gamma - (a-1)^gamma));
        phi_S(i,t) = 0;
        L_S(i,t) = (w(i,t)./(sigma*p_S(i,t).*(Z_S(i,t).^gamma))).^(1/(sigma-1));
    end    
    
    %Land Use and Land Rents
    R_M(i,t) = p_M(i,t)*((Z_M(i,t)*(phi_M(i,t)/(a-1)+1)).^gamma).*(L_M(i,t).^mu)-w(i,t).*L_M(i,t)- w(i,t)*(ksi1+ksi2*(1/(1-phi_M(i,t))));
    R_S(i,t) = p_S(i,t)*((Z_S(i,t)*(phi_S(i,t)/(a-1)+1)).^gamma).*(L_S(i,t).^sigma)-w(i,t).*L_S(i,t)- w(i,t)*(ksi1+ksi2*(1/(1-phi_S(i,t))));
    
    
    if R_M(i,t) > R_S(i,t)
        theta(i,t) = 1; 
        phi_S(i,t) = 0;
    else
        theta(i,t) = 0;
        phi_M(i,t) = 0;
    end
    
    %Expected Outputs
    M(i,t) = ((Z_M(i,t)*(phi_M(i,t)/(a-1)+1)).^gamma).*L_M(i,t).^mu;
    S(i,t) = ((Z_S(i,t)*(phi_S(i,t)/(a-1)+1)).^gamma).*L_S(i,t).^sigma;
    
    %Aggregate Labor
    L(i,t) = theta(i,t).*L_M(i,t)+(1-theta(i,t)).*L_S(i,t);
    
    %Construct Excess Supply
    if i > 1
        if phi_M(i,t) > 0
            ES_M(i,t) =  ES_M(i-1,t) + (theta(i,t)*(M(i,t)- (w(i,t)/p_M(i,t))*(ksi1+ksi2*(1/(1-phi_M(i,t))))) - c_M(i,t).*L(i,t) - kappa*(abs(ES_M(i-1,t))))/length(l);
        else
            ES_M(i,t) =  ES_M(i-1,t) + (theta(i,t)*M(i,t) - c_M(i,t).*L(i,t) - kappa*(abs(ES_M(i-1,t))))/length(l);
        end    
    else
        if phi_M(i,t) > 0
            ES_M(i,t) =  (theta(i,t)*(M(i,t)- (w(i,t)/p_M(i,t))*(ksi1+ksi2*(1/(1-phi_M(i,t))))) - c_M(i,t).*L(i,t))/length(l);
        else
            ES_M(i,t) =  (theta(i,t)*M(i,t) - c_M(i,t).*L(i,t))/length(l);
        end
    end
    
    %Construct prices for i+1
    if ES_M(i,t) > 0
        if i < length(l)
            p_M(i+1,t) = p_M(i,t)*exp(kappa/length(l));
        end
    else
        if i < length(l)
            p_M(i+1,t) = p_M(i,t)*exp(-kappa/length(l));
        end    
    end
    
    %Generate Poisson draws
    Po_M(i,t) = rand;
    Po_S(i,t) = rand;
    
    %Generate Pareto and update productivity after innovation
    if Po_M(i,t) > phi_M(i,t);
        Z_M(i,t) = Z_M(i,t);
    else
        z = gprnd(1/a,1/a,1);
        Z_M(i,t) = z*Z_M(i,t); 
    end
    if Po_S(i,t) > phi_S(i,t);
        Z_S(i,t) = Z_S(i,t);
    else
        z = gprnd(1/a,1/a,1);
        Z_S(i,t) = z*Z_S(i,t); 
    end
        
    %Actual Outputs
    M(i,t) = theta(i,t).*(Z_M(i,t).^gamma).*L_M(i,t).^mu;
    S(i,t) = (1-theta(i,t)).*(Z_S(i,t).^gamma).*L_S(i,t).^sigma;
        
end

%Equilibrium in the goods market 
if (Ubar(t) > 0) %&& sum((1-theta(:,t)).*L_S(:,t))/length(l) < 100);
    d1 = ES_M(length(l),t);
else
    d1 = 1000000;
end    

%Equilibrium condition in labor market

if (p_M(1,t)> 0)% && p_M(1,t) < pp)
    d2 = sum(L(:,t))/length(l) - Lbar; 
else
    d2 = 1000000;
end 

%Calculate Rental Income (RI)

if (RI(t) > 0 && min(w(:,t)) > 0)
    d3 = RI(t) - (sum(theta(:,t).*R_M(:,t)) + sum((1-theta(:,t)).*R_S(:,t)))/(Lbar*length(l));  
else
    d3 = 1000000;
end

D = [d1,d2,d3];
        






I've written the following code based on tips from Abdulaziz. However, I'm still unsure how to extract the variables w, Z_M, Z_S, Z_M_Mor, Z_S_Mor, c_M, c_S, p_M, p_S, M, S, L_M, L_S, L, R_M, R_S, phi_M, phi_S, theta, Po_M, Po_S, ES_M, Ubar, RI from SDsysFinal.m after using fsolve. In the original setup, D = SDsysFinal(X) served as the residual. I need guidance on how to return data excluding the residual D and access the aforementioned variables from the output of the fsolve function.

StatMonCarFinal.m


clear
clc

niter = 10; %number of random realizations for montecarlo

n1 = niter; 
n2 = 500;  
n3 = 240;

wMC        = zeros(n1, n2, n3);
Z_MMC      = zeros(n1, n2, n3);
Z_SMC      = zeros(n1, n2, n3);
Z_M_MorMC  = zeros(n1, n2, n3);
Z_S_MorMC  = zeros(n1, n2, n3);
c_MMC      = zeros(n1, n2, n3);
c_SMC      = zeros(n1, n2, n3);
p_MMC      = zeros(n1, n2, n3);
p_SMC      = zeros(n1, n2, n3);
MMC        = zeros(n1, n2, n3);
SMC        = zeros(n1, n2, n3);
L_MMC      = zeros(n1, n2, n3);
L_SMC      = zeros(n1, n2, n3);
LMC        = zeros(n1, n2, n3);
R_MMC      = zeros(n1, n2, n3);
R_SMC      = zeros(n1, n2, n3);
phi_MMC    = zeros(n1, n2, n3);
phi_SMC    = zeros(n1, n2, n3);
thetaMC    = zeros(n1, n2, n3);
Po_MMC     = zeros(n1, n2, n3);
Po_SMC     = zeros(n1, n2, n3);
ES_MMC     = zeros(n1, n2, n3);
UbarMC     = zeros(n1, n2, n3);
RIMC       = zeros(n1, n2, n3);
Z_MvecMC   = zeros(n1, n2, n3);
Z_SvecMC   = zeros(n1, n2, n3);


parfor mcar = 1:niter
    
    parsave(mcar, niter)

    mcar

    [w, Z_M, Z_S, Z_M_Mor, Z_S_Mor, c_M, c_S, p_M, p_S, M, S, ...
    L_M, L_S, L, R_M, R_S, phi_M, phi_S, theta, ...
    Po_M, Po_S, ES_M, Ubar, RI, Z_Mvec, Z_Svec]=SDMasterFinal();
    
    parsaveall(w, Z_M, Z_S, Z_M_Mor, Z_S_Mor, c_M, c_S, p_M, p_S, M, S, L_M, L_S, ...
        L, R_M, R_S, phi_M, phi_S, theta, Po_M, Po_S, ...
        ES_M, Ubar, RI, Z_Mvec, Z_Svec,mcar,niter)

end


clearvars -except niter
for mcar = 1:niter

    filename = sprintf('run_data/OutputFinal_mcar%d.mat', mcar);
    load(filename);
    
    wMC(mcar,:,:) = w;
    Z_MMC(mcar,:,:) = Z_M;
    Z_SMC(mcar,:,:) = Z_S;
    Z_M_MorMC(mcar,:,:) = Z_M_Mor;
    Z_S_MorMC(mcar,:,:) = Z_S_Mor;
    c_MMC(mcar,:,:) = c_M;
    c_SMC(mcar,:,:) = c_S;
    p_MMC(mcar,:,:) = p_M;
    p_SMC(mcar,:,:) = p_S;
    MMC(mcar,:,:) = M;
    SMC(mcar,:,:) = S;
    L_MMC(mcar,:,:) = L_M;
    L_SMC(mcar,:,:) = L_S;
    LMC(mcar,:,:) = L;
    R_MMC(mcar,:,:) = R_M;
    R_SMC(mcar,:,:) = R_S;
    phi_MMC(mcar,:,:) = phi_M;
    phi_SMC(mcar,:,:) = phi_S;
    thetaMC(mcar,:,:) = theta;
    Po_MMC(mcar,:,:) = Po_M;
    Po_SMC(mcar,:,:) = Po_S;
    ES_MMC(mcar,:,:) = ES_M;
    UbarMC(mcar,:,:) = Ubar;
    RIMC(mcar,:,:) = RI;
    Z_MvecMC(mcar,:,:) = Z_Mvec;
    Z_SvecMC(mcar,:,:) = Z_Svec;

    clearvars -except niter mcar *MC
end

save OutputFinal *MC niter

rmdir('run_data' ,'s');

    


SDMasterFinal.m

function [w, Z_M, Z_S, Z_M_Mor, Z_S_Mor, c_M, c_S, p_M, p_S, M, S, L_M, L_S, L, R_M, R_S, phi_M, phi_S, theta, Po_M, Po_S, ES_M, Ubar, RI, Z_Mvec, Z_Svec]=SDMasterFinal()

global w Z_M Z_S Z_M_Mor Z_S_Mor c_M c_S p_M p_S M S L_M L_S L R_M R_S phi_M phi_S theta Po_M Po_S ES_M Ubar RI

% Parameter Value
delta        = 7.5;                
T            = 240;                
l            = 1:500;              
                                   
params       = struct();           
params.delta = 7.5;                
params.h_M   = 0.9;                
params.h_S   = 1.4;                
params.alfa  = -1.5;               
params.gamma = 1 - 0.6;            
params.mu    = 0.6;                
params.sigma = 0.6;                
params.l     = l;                  
params.a     = 45;                 
params.ksi1  = 1.142793;           
params.ksi2  = 0.0082433;          
params.Lbar  = 100;                
params.kappa = 0.08;               
                                   
% Allocate variables
w       = zeros(length(l),T);                         
Z_M     = zeros(length(l),T);                         
Z_S     = zeros(length(l),T);                         
Z_M_Mor = zeros(length(l),T);                         
Z_S_Mor = zeros(length(l),T);                         
c_M     = zeros(length(l),T);                         
c_S     = zeros(length(l),T);                         
p_M     = zeros(length(l),T);                         
p_S     = zeros(length(l),T);                         
M       = zeros(length(l),T);                         
S       = zeros(length(l),T);                         
L_M     = zeros(length(l),T);                         
L_S     = zeros(length(l),T);                         
L       = zeros(length(l),T);                         
R_M     = zeros(length(l),T);                         
R_S     = zeros(length(l),T);                         
phi_M   = zeros(length(l),T);                         
phi_S   = zeros(length(l),T);                         
theta   = zeros(length(l),T);                         
Po_M    = zeros(length(l),T);                         
Po_S    = zeros(length(l),T);                         
ES_M    = zeros(length(l),T);                         
Ubar    = zeros(1, T);                                
RI      = zeros(1, T);                                
Z_Mvec  = zeros(length(l), length(l));                
Z_Svec  = zeros(length(l), length(l));                
                                                      
X0(1)   = 0.0492;  % Ubar(1) initial value for solver 
X0(2)   = 1.035;   % p_M(1,1) initial value for solver
X0(3)   = 0.054;   % RI(1) initial value for solver   

for t = 1:T

    %t
    params.t = t;

    %Initial Productivity
    if t == 1
        Z_M_Mor(:,1) = .8 + .4*l/length(l);
        Z_S_Mor(:,1) = 1*ones(length(l),1);
    end

    % F=@(R)SDsysFinal(R);
    F = @(X) SDsysFinal(X, params);
    options=optimset('MaxFunEvals',10000000000,'TolFun',0.0001,'MaxIter',1000000,'Display','off');
    [X,Eval] = fsolve(F,X0,options);

    X0(1) = Ubar(t);
    X0(2) = p_M(1,t);
    X0(3) = RI(t);

    %Eval

    %Diffusion
    for i = 1:length(l)
        for j = 1:length(l)
            Z_Mvec(i,j) = exp(-delta*abs(i-j)/length(l))*Z_M(j,t);
            Z_Svec(i,j) = exp(-delta*abs(i-j)/length(l))*Z_S(j,t);
        end
        Z_M(i,t+1) = max(Z_Mvec(i,:));
        Z_S(i,t+1) = max(Z_Svec(i,:));

        %Save Morning Productivity
        Z_M_Mor(:,t+1) = Z_M(:,t+1);
        Z_S_Mor(:,t+1) = Z_S(:,t+1);
    end

end


end




SDsysFinal.m

function D = SDsysFinal(X, params)

t     = params.t;         
h_M   = params.h_M;       
h_S   = params.h_S;       
alfa  = params.alfa;      
gamma = params.gamma;     
mu    = params.mu;        
sigma = params.sigma;     
l     = params.l;         
a     = params.a;         
ksi1  = params.ksi1;      
ksi2  = params.ksi2;      
Lbar  = params.Lbar;      
kappa = params.kappa;     

global w Z_M Z_S Z_M_Mor Z_S_Mor c_M c_S p_M p_S M S L_M L_S L R_M R_S phi_M phi_S theta Po_M Po_S ES_M Ubar RI

p_S(:,t) = ones(length(l),1);

Ubar(t) = X(1);
p_M(1,t) = X(2);
RI(t) = X(3);

Z_M(:,t) = Z_M_Mor(:,t);
Z_S(:,t) = Z_S_Mor(:,t);

for i = 1:length(l)

    %Wages and consumption
    w(i,t) = Ubar(t)*((((p_M(i,t)./h_M)/(p_S(i,t)./h_S))^(1/(alfa-1)))*p_M(i,t) + p_S(i,t))...
        ./(h_M*(((p_M(i,t)./h_M)/(p_S(i,t)./h_S))^(alfa/(alfa-1))) + h_S).^(1/alfa) - RI(t);

    c_S(i,t) = (w(i,t) + RI(t))./(p_M(i,t).*(((p_M(i,t)./h_M)/(p_S(i,t)./h_S))^(1/(alfa-1)))+p_S(i,t));
    c_M(i,t) = c_S(i,t).*(((p_M(i,t)./h_M)/(p_S(i,t)./h_S))^(1/(alfa-1)));

    %Choose phi
    phi_M(i,t) = 1-((Z_M(i,t)*p_M(i,t)*gamma)/(ksi2*(a-1)*((w(i,t)/(mu*p_M(i,t)))^((1-gamma)/gamma))))^(-1/2);
    phi_S(i,t) = 1-((Z_S(i,t)*p_S(i,t)*gamma)/(ksi2*(a-1)*((w(i,t)/(sigma*p_S(i,t)))^((1-gamma)/gamma))))^(-1/2);

    if phi_M(i,t) < 0
        phi_M(i,t) = 0;
    end
    if phi_M(i,t) > 1
        phi_M(i,t) = 1;
    end
    if phi_S(i,t) < 0
        phi_S(i,t) = 0;
    end
    if phi_S(i,t) > 1
        phi_S(i,t) = 1;
    end

    %Production and labor choices
    L_M(i,t) = (w(i,t)./(mu*p_M(i,t).*((Z_M(i,t)*(phi_M(i,t)/(a-1)+1)).^gamma))).^(1/(mu-1));
    L_S(i,t) = (w(i,t)./(sigma*p_S(i,t).*((Z_S(i,t)*(phi_S(i,t)/(a-1)+1)).^gamma))).^(1/(sigma-1));

    if (ksi1 + ksi2*(1/(1-phi_M(i,t))))*w(i,t) > (((Z_M(i,t)).^gamma)*p_M(i,t).*(L_M(i,t).^mu)/((a-1)^gamma))...
            *(((phi_M(i,t)+a-1)^gamma - (a-1)^gamma))
        phi_M(i,t) = 0;
        L_M(i,t) = (w(i,t)./(mu*p_M(i,t).*(Z_M(i,t).^gamma))).^(1/(mu-1));
    end
    if (ksi1 + ksi2*(1/(1-phi_S(i,t))))*w(i,t) > (((Z_S(i,t)).^gamma)*p_S(i,t).*(L_S(i,t).^sigma)/((a-1)^gamma))...
            *(((phi_S(i,t)+a-1)^gamma - (a-1)^gamma))
        phi_S(i,t) = 0;
        L_S(i,t) = (w(i,t)./(sigma*p_S(i,t).*(Z_S(i,t).^gamma))).^(1/(sigma-1));
    end

    %Land Use and Land Rents
    R_M(i,t) = p_M(i,t)*((Z_M(i,t)*(phi_M(i,t)/(a-1)+1)).^gamma).*(L_M(i,t).^mu)-w(i,t).*L_M(i,t)- w(i,t)*(ksi1+ksi2*(1/(1-phi_M(i,t))));
    R_S(i,t) = p_S(i,t)*((Z_S(i,t)*(phi_S(i,t)/(a-1)+1)).^gamma).*(L_S(i,t).^sigma)-w(i,t).*L_S(i,t)- w(i,t)*(ksi1+ksi2*(1/(1-phi_S(i,t))));


    if R_M(i,t) > R_S(i,t)
        theta(i,t) = 1;
        phi_S(i,t) = 0;
    else
        theta(i,t) = 0;
        phi_M(i,t) = 0;
    end

    %Expected Outputs
    M(i,t) = ((Z_M(i,t)*(phi_M(i,t)/(a-1)+1)).^gamma).*L_M(i,t).^mu;
    S(i,t) = ((Z_S(i,t)*(phi_S(i,t)/(a-1)+1)).^gamma).*L_S(i,t).^sigma;

    %Aggregate Labor
    L(i,t) = theta(i,t).*L_M(i,t)+(1-theta(i,t)).*L_S(i,t);

    %Construct Excess Supply
    if i > 1
        if phi_M(i,t) > 0
            ES_M(i,t) =  ES_M(i-1,t) + (theta(i,t)*(M(i,t)- (w(i,t)/p_M(i,t))*(ksi1+ksi2*(1/(1-phi_M(i,t))))) - c_M(i,t).*L(i,t) - kappa*(abs(ES_M(i-1,t))))/length(l);
        else
            ES_M(i,t) =  ES_M(i-1,t) + (theta(i,t)*M(i,t) - c_M(i,t).*L(i,t) - kappa*(abs(ES_M(i-1,t))))/length(l);
        end
    else
        if phi_M(i,t) > 0
            ES_M(i,t) =  (theta(i,t)*(M(i,t)- (w(i,t)/p_M(i,t))*(ksi1+ksi2*(1/(1-phi_M(i,t))))) - c_M(i,t).*L(i,t))/length(l);
        else
            ES_M(i,t) =  (theta(i,t)*M(i,t) - c_M(i,t).*L(i,t))/length(l);
        end
    end

    %Construct prices for i+1
    if ES_M(i,t) > 0
        if i < length(l)
            p_M(i+1,t) = p_M(i,t)*exp(kappa/length(l));
        end
    else
        if i < length(l)
            p_M(i+1,t) = p_M(i,t)*exp(-kappa/length(l));
        end
    end

    %Generate Poisson draws
    Po_M(i,t) = rand;
    Po_S(i,t) = rand;

    %Generate Pareto and update productivity after innovation
    if Po_M(i,t) > phi_M(i,t)
        Z_M(i,t) = Z_M(i,t);
    else
        z = gprnd(1/a,1/a,1);
        Z_M(i,t) = z*Z_M(i,t);
    end
    if Po_S(i,t) > phi_S(i,t)
        Z_S(i,t) = Z_S(i,t);
    else
        z = gprnd(1/a,1/a,1);
        Z_S(i,t) = z*Z_S(i,t);
    end

    %Actual Outputs
    M(i,t) = theta(i,t).*(Z_M(i,t).^gamma).*L_M(i,t).^mu;
    S(i,t) = (1-theta(i,t)).*(Z_S(i,t).^gamma).*L_S(i,t).^sigma;

end

%Equilibrium in the goods market
if (Ubar(t) > 0) %&& sum((1-theta(:,t)).*L_S(:,t))/length(l) < 100);
    d1 = ES_M(length(l),t);
else
    d1 = 1000000;
end

%Equilibrium condition in labor market

if (p_M(1,t)> 0)% && p_M(1,t) < pp)
    d2 = sum(L(:,t))/length(l) - Lbar;
else
    d2 = 1000000;
end

%Calculate Rental Income (RI)

if (RI(t) > 0 && min(w(:,t)) > 0)
    d3 = RI(t) - (sum(theta(:,t).*R_M(:,t)) + sum((1-theta(:,t)).*R_S(:,t)))/(Lbar*length(l));
else
    d3 = 1000000;
end

D = [d1,d2,d3];





parsaveall.m

function parsaveall(w, Z_M, Z_S, Z_M_Mor, Z_S_Mor, c_M, c_S, p_M, p_S, M, S, L_M, L_S, ...
        L, R_M, R_S, phi_M, phi_S, theta, Po_M, Po_S, ...
        ES_M, Ubar, RI, Z_Mvec, Z_Svec,mcar,niter)

    if ~exist('run_data', 'dir')
        mkdir('run_data');
    end
    
    filename = sprintf('run_data/OutputFinal_mcar%d.mat', mcar);
    
    save(filename, 'w', 'Z_M', 'Z_S', 'Z_M_Mor', 'Z_S_Mor', 'c_M', 'c_S', ...
        'p_M', 'p_S', 'M', 'S', 'L_M', 'L_S', 'L', ...
        'R_M', 'R_S', 'phi_M', 'phi_S', 'theta', 'Po_M', 'Po_S',  ...
         'ES_M', 'Ubar', 'RI', 'Z_Mvec', 'Z_Svec', 'mcar', 'niter');

end


`parsave.m``

function parsave(mcar, niter)
  save mcar mcar  niter
end



MATLAB indicates that the save command cannot be used within a parfor loop. I'm not sure how to overcome this limitation.

You can make a function to do the save inside forloop something like this:
function parsave(fname, x,y)
  save(fname, 'x', 'y')
end


I am also concerned about the extensive use of global variables in SDMasterFinal.m, which might conflict with the parallelism of parfor.

I would recommend not using global at all it is harder to debug i suggest editing your code to use functions whenever you can so that it will be easier to implement MC.
You can make a struct called states for example inside that include all the wanted variables and include it in the functions. I would recommend using smaller struct so you know exactly what is in and out of the function

Thanks @Abdulaziz. Using states makes it easy to pass parameters and data to functions; however, I'm uncertain about how to manage the data returned by the computation after calling SDsysFinal(X) with fsolve, where the original return value D in D = SDsysFinal(X) served as a convergence criterion.
